# Matlab - Access index of max value in for loop and use it to remove values from array

Tags: matlab, for-loop, eval, printf

I would like to recursively find the maximum value in a series of matrices (column 8, to be specific), then use the index of that maximum value to set all values in the array with index up to the max index to NaN (for columns 14:16). It is straight forward to find the max value and index, but using a for loop to do it for multiple arrays I am stumped.

Here is how I can do it without a for loop:

```
[C,Max] = max(wy2000(:,8));
wy2000(1:Max,14:16) = NaN;
[C,Max] = max(wy2001(:,8));
wy2001(1:Max,14:16) = NaN;
[C,Max] = max(wy2002(:,8));
wy2002(1:Max,14:16) = NaN;
```

and so on and so forth...

Here are two ways I have tried using a for loop:

```
startyear = 2000;
endyear = 2009;
for n=startyear:endyear
    currentYear = sprintf('wy%d',n);
    [C,Max] = max(currentYear(:,8));
    currentYear(1:Max,14:16) = NaN;
end
```

Here is another way I tried, using the eval function

```
for n=2000:2009;
    currentYear = ['wy' int2str(n)];
    var2 = ['maxswe' int2str(n)];
    eval([var2 ' = max(currentYear(:,8))']);
end
```

In both cases, the problem seems to be that MATLAB doesn't recognize the 'currentYear' variable to be the array that corresponds to the wyXXXX that I already have created in my workspace.

Based on Peters answer, here is some more info about my data. I am starting with a matrix of data called all_data which holds 16 columns of data, spanning the time period 1982 - 2012. I am only interested in the period 2000 - 2009, and I am also interested in analyzing each year individually (2000, 2001,...,2009).

To get the data into individual years, I use the following code:

```
for n=2000:2009;
s = datenum(n-1,10,1);
e = datenum(n,9,30);
startcell = find(TIME(:,7)==s);
endcell = find(TIME(:,7)==e);
var1 = ['wy' int2str(n)];
eval([var1 '= all_data3(startcell:endcell,:)']);
eval(['save ', var1]);
end
```

For clarification, it is the period 10/1/YEAR1 to 9/30/YEAR2 that I am interested in, and TIME is a matrix holding the dates and times of my data.
So at the end of the above for-loop, I have a new matrix for each water-year (wy). I then want to find the date of maximum snow-accumulation (column 8) and exclude all data prior to that date from my analysis. this is where the original question comes from.

Peter's solution works, but I was hoping to find a more simple solution to find the max date and set the values prior to that date to NaN, without having to declare a bunch of variables (or entries in a cell array).

If I could write a loop that would create the cell array that Peter suggested based on a start and end year, that would make the code transferable to other datasets, but when i try to do this I run into the issue that the index for the cell-array is 1:length(years), but the wy arrays are named according to the actual year, so there is an inconsistency when using the eval function.

Matt

Comment: A general way to avoid eval: http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F

Comment: @OlegKomarov Thank you for the link. As a beginner user, it seems strange that Matlab doesn't work well with dynamically named variable. But I am already starting to see the advantages to the cell array system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've discovered the problem with `eval` and dynamically named variables.  They're messy.  I'd recommend recoding this as a cell array, with the cell array index being the index for the year:

```
years = 2000:2009;
wy{1} = wy2000;
wy{2} = wy2001;
% etc...

% Then,
for n=1:length(years)
    [C, maxval] = max(wy{n}(:,8));
    % etc.
end
```

You really only need the actual year when you input the data and when you display it.  Now, if you're starting from a huge pile of arrays already named this way, that's the time to use `eval`: to convert them into this form that's easier to use.  Just form the eval strings so they read, for example, `'wy{1} = wy2000;'`

Comment: Exactly. Variable names should not be used to store data (the year in this case)!

Comment: Peter - That solution does work, however it still seems quite cumbersome. I still have to define the wy{1} = wy2000....wy{10} = wy2009 cell array. By that time, I might as well just do it the way I outlined above without the for loop. I'll provide some more information about where I am starting from.

Comment: @mr.cooper NO! You wouldn't be wasting time here because of your erroneous data organization in the first place. Therefore, do yourself a favor and correct the data generation at the core. Avoid `eval()`.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I agree, and I would like to correct the erroneous data organization at the core. If you have a suggestion for how to do that, please share it. I am very much a beginner, however it seems like there should be a very simple way to do what I am asking. Surely, it is very common to loop through a bunch of arrays that are named sequentially and perform an operation on each array, but it seems difficult to use Matlab to access arrays in a loop using the name of the array. I realize I am missing something fundamentally - can you explain where I am going wrong at the core?

Comment: @Peter After working with the cell array to perform additional operations, I see how much better it works to create the cell array from the start. For example, I was able to write a loop that performed multiple linear regression using columns from the different cell arrays. Thanks Peter!